# PHP Query Fail - "q fail"

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'zuk1_boo';
$dbpass = 'lols';
$dbname = 'zuk1_boo';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$iq = $_POST['iq'];

$nuname = str_replace(" ", "-", $name);
$nuname = $nuname.".gif";
$path = "img/$nuname";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$path);

$query = "INSERT INTO celebs (celeb,path1,iqq) VALUES ('$name','$path','$iq')";

mysql_query($query) or die('q fail');

mysql_close($conn);

echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
<tr>
<tr><td><input name="name" type="text" value="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="iq" type="text" value="iq"></td></tr>
<td width="246">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
</td>
<td width="80"><input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Bear in mind there is an ID row with auto increment but even if I add that to the query it still won't work.

No matter what I do with this query it just WILL not work, I've triple checked the sql details and they are fine, even though it appears to be connecting fine anyway. I've played with the field names in the query and they should be fine but it just won't work!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
mysql_query($query) or die('q fail');
```

Replace this with

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

And tell us what you get.

Comment: I'm an absolute d*ck head, that's what you get. DB not selected. Sometimes I get so frustrated with problems I miss the obvious :)

Comment: Half the time my coworkers come to me with an SQL problem, they haven't checked mysql_error(), and when they do the answer is obvious.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: here, have 5 Monopoly dollars

Answer (score 6):

Well, now that you've solved the actual problem, I think it's good to point out that you have massive gaping [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) holes.

The ideal way to fix would be switching to using the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) functions and use parameterized queries, but the quickest fix would be to change these lines:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$iq = $_POST['iq'];
```

to

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$iq = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['iq']);
```

The code you have now would be extremely unsafe to make public.

Comment: Thanks for your help, didn't bother looking into securing it because this will be password protected and used for admin only. But good for future reference!

Comment: You should never count on that for security. If someone guessed the password, they could have full access to your database, instead of just being able to use the admin tools.

Comment: Chad, I wish I could up-vote that comment more than once. Never trust input - reguardless of where it comes from or who will theoretically be able to see it.